# Blazor Component - inherit from generic BaseClass

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have a base component that looks like this:

**CatalogTableBase.razor.cs** (CodeBehind of CatalogTableBase.razor)

```cs
public class CatalogTableBase<T>
    {

        [Parameter]
        public IEnumerable<Feature<T>>? FeatureList { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public List<string>? FeatureGroupProperties { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public bool ShowHeader { get; set; } = true;

    }
```

Now, i want to create 2 different child-components which once implement a `string` as the generically passed type and once a `double`.

**FeatureRangeCatalogTable.razor**

```cs
@inherits CatalogTableBase<double>

<div>
...
</div>
```

This throws the [CS0115](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0115?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0115)) Error. `(FeatureRangeCatalogTable.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder): no suitable method found to override)`


I guess the thrown error has something to do with the interpreter not knowing what to do with the `@inherits`-line.
I can't wrap around my head why this wouldn't work. Inheriting the class in the code behind (`FeatureRangeCatalogTable.razor.cs`) also doesn't work.

#### TL:DR

How do i implement generic base classes in blazor components?

Comment: You do have `CatalogTableBase.razor` file, right? With an @typeparam.  That isn't 100% clear here.

Comment: Also post full error details. Which base method can't be found?

Comment: Yes, both files are/have code-behinds

Comment: I think that CatalogTableBase<T> has to inherit after ComponentBase or similar to have BuildRenderTree available https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#component-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CatalogTableBase has to inherit after ComponentBase or similar to have BuildRenderTree available [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#component-classes)